# vmware SRM test recovery including domain controller

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012, vmware-srm

i need to have Domain services including DNS in an isolated network for use with SRM test recovery plans. I am fairly sure that i dont need to do anything specific to achieve this other than clone a DC with global catalogue and DNS (dont need FSMO roles as i wont be making any changes in the isolated network), i believe the process is:

power down the target DC VM (in the recovery site) > clone > power on the target DC VM > edit the new VM to be on the isolated network > power on the new VM

i will do this manually initially but potentially look to move toward automating this daily or just initiate it at SRM test invocation (not too bothered about that right now).

Ive done some research and dont believe there is anything else i need to do or be aware of when cloning the DC. I know there is general guidance about cloning a DC to create a real DC in the same forest, but thats not what i am doing, as far as the isolated network DC VM is concerned, it will just lose its replication partners?

just wanted to make sure i hadnt missed something obvious or if there are any gotchas that i should be aware of?

thanks

Comment: `it will just lose its replication partners?` If there is only one DC, there is no replication. Also, if that DC does not have all of the roles, it's fairly typical to seize the roles in a recovery environment.

Comment: @GregAskew this is not for DR....like i said, its specifically for DR testing, i will be using the recovery plan "Test" option